# Issues Rendering Highcharts - Populating through PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, highcharts

I'm hoping someone can help me here, I've been looking at highcharts as a way of graphing my dynamic data from my sql db....What I've come up with so far is below, it's strange, it seems correct, the data is correct, however, I can't get my chart to render, now I've tried viewing the chart through both Chrome and IE but with no results, can anyone see where I might've gone wrong, or where there is an error...my data is passing into the JS arrays, so there's an issue with the rendering end... Any help would be much appreciated.  I have closed off my html tag, but for some reason it isn't displaying in this post...if anyone has any suggestions I would be happy to hear them!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>  
<script src='highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>       
    <script src='exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>    

    </head>

<body>

    <?php
    include "connect_db.php";

    $SQL1 =     "SELECT review.reviewForum AS reviewForum, 
                COUNT(CASE WHEN mom.result = 'Approved' THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END) AS Approved, 
                COUNT(CASE WHEN mom.result = 'NOT Approved' THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END) AS Not_Approved, 
                COUNT(CASE WHEN mom.result = 'Cancelled' THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END) AS Cancelled 
                FROM review INNER JOIN mom ON mom.reviewId = review.reviewId GROUP BY review.reviewForum";

    $result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
    $data1 = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
       $data1[] = $row['reviewForum'];
    }

    $result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);
    $data2 = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
       $data2[] = $row['Approved'];
    }

    $result3 = mysql_query($SQL1);
    $data3 = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
       $data3[] = $row['Not_Approved'];
    }

    $result4= mysql_query($SQL1);
    $data4 = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
       $data4[] = $row['Cancelled'];
    }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
              chart: {
                 renderTo: 'container',
                 type: 'column'
              },

            title:  {
                        text: 'TC REVIEW RESULT STATS'
                    },

            xAxis:  {
                        categories: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
                    },

            yAxis:  {
                        min:0
                    },

            legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 50,
                        y: 35,
                        floating: true,
                        shadow: true
                    },

            plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                                        borderWidth: 0
                                    }
                        },

            series: [   {
                            name: 'Approved',
                            data: [<?php echo join($data2, ',') ?>],
                            pointStart: 0
                            //pointInterval
                        },

                        {

                            name: 'Unapproved',
                            data: [<?php echo join($data3, ',') ?>],
                            pointStart: 0
                            //pointInterval
                        },

                        {
                            name: 'Cancelled',
                            data: [<?php echo join($data4, ',') ?>],
                            pointStart: 0
                            //pointInterval
                        },
                    ]
        });
});
    </script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your html tag might be missing because you probably need to put an additional enter after that line (to let it be part of the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the comma after the categories statement under xAxis.

```
 xAxis:  {
     categories: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
 },
```

Should be

```
xAxis:  {
    categories: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>]
},
```

Comment: the comma is not the issue here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/m2uXc/) with comma after the object array

Comment: Hi...I've also done that, but with no difference..thank you though

Comment: Try: categories: ['<?php echo join($data1, "','") ?>']

Comment: Thank you..that contributed to solving the problem, both that and I removed the pointStart: 0 AND pointInterval, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start trying to render one without generated code. If that doesnt work, you might want to share that on jsfiddle and we can have a look :-). If it does work, you should compare it with the generated code.

```
    {
        name: 'Cancelled',
        data: [<?php echo join($data4, ',') ?>],
        pointStart: 0
        //pointInterval
    }, // This comma is a syntax error
]
```

Do you see that comma? You don't put commas before '}', because you have that in multiple places.

Comment: To be honest EricG I was hoping I might have someone have a look over my code with fresh eyes, as I've been going square eyed for the last two days...  I'm just wondering if my layout is ok etc...is it ok to have the js within the php file? etc

Comment: The one after cancelled, data or the closing brace?

Comment: Sorry, I can see why, I deleted it but when I upload it and re-run it, there is still no rendering.  I have run it through, Google Chrome -> Developer Tools and it tells me I have an error   @                                                                       
             xAxis:  { categories: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?],
                    },    It says undefined identifier??

Comment: I'm unable to comment code for some reason..apologies for the messy reply

Comment: No problem. You still have too much commas. Remove all commas before '}'

Answer (score 0):

I think thre real reason is here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src='highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>       
<script src='exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
```

First load jQuery, then Highcharts.